# ARKit resetting session crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, crash, arkit, sceneview

I am trying to restart the `sceneView.session` by using a function called `restartSession()`. I found that I was getting random crashes when calling this function.

My `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
    self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    self.sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
}
```

My `restartSession()` function:

```
func restartSession() {
    self.sceneView.session.pause()
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
    self.sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

I am running Xcode 9.4 beta and iOS 11.3.1

Comment: What kind of crashes? Any specific errors? Is it while you are enumerating through the nodes or afterwards?

Comment: I think the issue is the enumerateChildNodes function. I have had random crashes using this as well